# Windows 10 cannot see files from last CD session

Tags: windows-10, cd-r

I have a multi-session CD-R, I can see all my sessions and files with Cd Burner Xp "info disc" utility but if I check in Windows's explorer I can see files until the last but one session. If I push F5 or right click-refresh I still see the last but one files and not the last one.

Why? Is this a Win10 issue?

Comment: Windows Explorer shows on the latest version of the CD. Other write updates are not shown

Comment: This is what I want, but I see the last but one session, not le latest.

Comment: Oh. Let me check and get back to you